# Windows Batch File for loop and line continuation

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, windows-7, imagemagick

I need a script for filling in all possible combinations of 5 blocks in a 3 by 3 grid. So I figured I could use ImageMagick for the coloring and a txt file for input. The text file consists of one number per line, the number shows which block should be colored. 5 numbers form one possible combination.

I use a for loop to read my txt file line for line. A variable (called a) is incremented and when it reaches 5 it is reset to 0 and another variable (called n) gets incremented, which changes the name of the output file. Since I need to reload the original image each time a new combination starts I use another variable (name) to switch between the original image and the picture for every combination.

This is my first time writing a batch file. So I might have not fully understood how line continuation and variables work since my script produces no output.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set a=0
set n=0
for /F %%G in (test.txt) do ^
set /A a=a+1 & ^
if !a!==5 set a=0  & set /A n=n+1 & ^
if !a!==0 set name=original.png else set name=output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 1 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 50 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 2 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 50 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 3 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 50 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 4 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 150 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 5 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 150 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 6 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 150 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 7 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 250 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 8 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 250 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png ^
if %%G == 9 magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 250 floodfill" %name% output_!n!.png
Pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code reformatted only, *(apart from the new first line)*:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set a=0
set n=0
for /F %%G in (test.txt) do (
    set /A a=a+1
    if !a!==5 (set a=0)
    set /A n=n+1
    if !a!==0 (set name=original.png) else (set name=output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==1 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 50 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==2 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 50 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==3 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 50 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==4 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 150 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==5 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 150 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==6 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 150 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==7 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 50, 250 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==8 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 150, 250 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
    if %%G==9 (magick convert -fill blue -draw "color 250, 250 floodfill" !name! output_!n!.png)
)
Pause
```

I have updated the code to fix a major issue with your name variables.

Comment: There were some other errors (logic) but thanks to your awesome formatting fixing them was easy! It works now.

Comment: fixed the main issue